# slow count on text column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, t-sql

Table t1 with 500k rows, 2TB in size, one text column. SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [TId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Weight] [int] NULL,
    [TDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [text_column] [text] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] [varchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TId] ASC
)
```

This is running forever:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE text_column IS NOT NULL
```

Unable to change the table, can only fix this with new indexes. But can't create an index on the text column. No experience with full text indexes.

What should I do to improve it, please ?

Comment: What is the actual question?  How to improve the table? If so, show us the CREATE TABLE script, including existing indexes.

Comment: An index on the text column might not be the best idea anyway, even if it were possible, but why not a filtered index? `CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.t1(key) WHERE text_column IS NOT NULL;` - then you can even get  the count from the metadata instead of a manual count against the table. (Also, why are you using `text`? This data type has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005.)

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Took about 15 minutes to build the index, but problem solved. There was actually a more complex query filtering on that text column, being executed 10k times daily, cleared most of the blocking now !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a filtered index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_valid_text_column 
  ON dbo.t1(Tid) 
  WHERE text_column IS NOT NULL;
```

Now your query should be able to use that index instead of the clustered index, and it should be much more efficient.

Even better, it enables you to look at the metadata views, so you read one row (or a number of rows equal to the number of partitions) instead of doing any sort of manual count:

```
SELECT SUM(p.rows) 
FROM sys.partitions AS p
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
  ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
  AND o.[index_id] = i.[index_id]
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON t.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE t.name = N't1'
  AND t.[schema_id] = 1
  AND i.name = N'ix_valid_text_column';
```

The query looks uglier but it will be far more efficient (in spite of what the execution plan may tell you), especially if the number of non-NULL values is small, and especially if the table is high-volume (your current query can block and can be blocked).